# Is there any way to check for import errors on airflow dag deploy

Tags: airflow, cicd

I have a python script that copies dag to airflow server via ssh and in 10 minutes or so it can be found in airflow ui.
But if the dag has errors then it's not shown in "All" tab and a warning banner with "DAG import errors" appears.
Is there any way to force dag validation on deploy so i can fail my deploy script if there're any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're using the Airflow CLI or Astro CLI, but the Astro CLI contains pytest commands, read [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/astro/cli/astro-dev-pytest) and the Astro CLI will initialize all projects with a sample pytest file that checks for import errors when your Airflow deployment is deployed.

More recent versions of Airflow also have the `dag.test()` command that can be added to your DAG file. You can read about this [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/executor/debug.html#testing-dags-with-dag-test).

To use the `dag.test()` just add the following to the bottom of your file

```py
if __name__=="__main__":
    dag.test()
```

then run in bash

```bash
> python your_dag_file.py
```

This should pick up any import errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a test in your CI/CD that's commonly referred to as the "DAG integrity test": https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-testing-skeleton/blob/4cc5e74e7cc8452677c1a9aa32b8917f8a822ddd/tests/dags/test_dag_integrity.py#L11-L12.

The essential code is:

```py
dag_bag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
assert not dag_bag.import_errors
```

A `DagBag` is a class in Airflow responsible for reading a file/directory to load DAGs, and there's a property named `import_errors` that contains import errors, if any.

This test does require some setup in your CI/CD pipeline to get working though. Here's a `conftest.py` file to automatically create a database for the duration of your test session: https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-testing-skeleton/blob/master/tests/conftest.py. The essential part here is:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def reset_db():
    from airflow.utils import db

    db.resetdb()
    yield
```

Which creates an empty database available to all tests in the testing session.